# UWP encrypt/decrypt XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, encryption, uwp, xmlserializer

I´am looking forward to secure my XML file with a security standard.
Unfortunately, I could not find a proper way to encrypt/decrypt my data.

I need to encrypt the file before it´s getting created.
How can I secure my file, else ?

Here´s a snippet of my XMLSerializer

```
   public static async Task SaveObjectToXml<T>(T objectToSave,string Path , string filename)
    {


        // stores an object in XML format in file called 'filename'
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(Path);
        StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(filename,CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
        using (stream)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stream, objectToSave);
        }

    }
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialize your object to XML string, encrypt it using something standard like AES and save it to file.

Comment: That was the idea. Have you an idea how to encrypt the string to AES ?? I have read a post on the microsoft forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/52080335-0016-4370-889b-3afe0c0dcb7a/how-to-do-simple-aes-encryptiondecryption-in-metro?forum=winappswithcsharp ....    the last question is to understand for what the "string pass" is needed and how I can create it.

Comment: It is running perfectly now! Thank you for your help